# 'Jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on windows 11

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYlvn.png)

I'm on windows 11. I tried installing python 3.8 and 3.11 and tiping in cmd: pip install notebook; it downloaded all the versions but jupyter still didn't work, it continues saying that is not recognized. I searched videos o posts but i couldn't resolv it.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have not updated your `PATH` environment variable to contain the directory where jupyter was installed.

Comment: Is "C:\Users\mirko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\" added to your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: check versions `pip -V` and `python -V`. Pythons don't share modules - if your `pip` install module for one Python then other Python will not have it. Maybe better use `/full/path/to/python3.8 -m pip install ...` and `/full/path/to/python3.11 -m pip install ...`

Comment: I 'm not sure if it should be `pip install notebook` or `pip install jupyter`

Comment: you may also try to run `python3 -m jupyter notebook` or `python3 -m notebook`

Comment: if you install `pip install jupyterlab` then should work also `python3 -m jupyter lab`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.